# TinyXML and problem with tags and formatting

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have a problem with TinyXML that can't be able to fix. I have extended an MFC application using C++ for work. The application does automated testing. After it completes it saves all the data in an XML file. Below the beginning of my DOM tree.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestData>
<Operator>Alex</Operator>
<ParentBarCode>12345
</ParentBarCode>
<Measurements>
```

The issue is the library seems to be adding a random newline after 12345. It should be:

```xml
<ParentBarCode>12345</ParentBarCode>
```

Could you help me please? I have tried everything... Code snippet below. Also, is there any way to remove a newline before closing the tag of a new element , i.e. before

```xml
</ParentBarCode>??
```

```cpp
//Code starts here
TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0","utf-8", "");
//doc.FirstChildElement();
doc.LinkEndChild(decl);
TiXmlElement *rootelement = new TiXmlElement("TestData");
doc.LinkEndChild(rootelement);
TiXmlText *textTestData = new TiXmlText("");
rootelement->LinkEndChild(textTestData);
//Operator node
TiXmlElement *Operator = new TiXmlElement("Operator"); 
//Tree root
rootelement->LinkEndChild(Operator);
TiXmlText *textOperator = new TiXmlText("Alex");
Operator->LinkEndChild(textOperator);
//ParentBarcode Node
TiXmlElement *barcode = new TiXmlElement("ParentBarCode"); 
//Tree root
rootelement->LinkEndChild(barcode);

//saving serial to a stringstream

stringstream serial;
serial << (DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber);
std::string myserial = serial.str();
//Removing spaces
myserial.erase(std::remove_if(myserial.begin(),     myserial.end(),::isspace), myserial.end());

char buffer[sizeof(myserial) + 1];
//int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(myserial), "%05ld", DlgPtr>m_lSerialNumber);
int ret = sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(myserial), "%05ld", myserial);
const char * charSerial = buffer;
TiXmlText *textbarcode = new TiXmlText(charSerial);
barcode->LinkEndChild(textbarcode);
```

No error messages, just the element's tag doesn't close on the same line.
I made a small sandbox project with the exact same DOM tree but it worked fine there. I was thinking maybe there is another issue I don't see with sprintf_s?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: change `sizeof(myserial)` to `myserial.size()`

Comment: or just use `TiXmlText *textbarcode = new TiXmlText(myserial.cstr());`

Comment: `sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(myserial), "%05ld", myserial);` is completely wrong

Comment: Okay. How would you do it instead?

    int ret = snprintf_s (buffer, sizeof(myserial), "%05ld", 
DlgPtr>m_lSerialNumber);

seems to work fine in the code. Still new to C++ programming btw.

Comment: If that line works why is it commented out? Show a [mre] with the actual code that is causing your issue

Answer (score 0):

As @AlanBirtles poked at in the comments, this part of your code is not great:

```
stringstream serial;
serial << (DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber);
std::string myserial = serial.str();
//Removing spaces
myserial.erase(std::remove_if(myserial.begin(),     myserial.end(),::isspace), myserial.end());

char buffer[sizeof(myserial) + 1];
int ret = sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(myserial), "%05ld", myserial);
const char * charSerial = buffer;
TiXmlText *textbarcode = new TiXmlText(charSerial);
barcode->LinkEndChild(textbarcode);
```

You start out strong by converting `DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber` into a `std::string`:

```
stringstream serial;
serial << (DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber);
std::string myserial = serial.str();
```

This is fine, though from C++11 forward you could also just do:

```
std::string myserial = std::to_string(DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber);
```

Then you remove spaces from `myserial`, which doesn't hurt - but I'm pretty sure there won't be any to remove, since you have just constructed the string from a single integer.

This is then where it starts going wrong.

You make a char-array buffer to write your number in, but you size that with `sizeof(myserial)`, which gives you the number of bytes that the object takes up in memory, including bookkeeping stuff, vtable pointers, etc. So you wind up allocating too much space here; `myserial.size()` would give you a better fit.

Then you try to use `sprintf_s` to write the number to the new buffer, but you use `"%05ld"` as the format string and a std::string as the argument - that just won't work. `"%05ld"` tells `sprintf_s` to expect an integer as input (and pad it to 5 digits with extra zeros), so it just takes that argument, casts it to an int, and interprets the first 4 bytes as a number - which makes no sense, and probably invokes undefined behavior.

Not only does this not do what you want it to do, you already have a string with your number in it, and can just call `myserial.c_str()` to get a `const char*` with the contents of `myserial`. This means that the entire second section could be replaced by:

```
TiXmlText *textbarcode = new TiXmlText(std::to_string(DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber).c_str());
barcode->LinkEndChild(textbarcode);
```

Comment: I have made some changes as advised. Using
    TiXmlText *textbarcode = new TiXmlText(std::to_string(DlgPtr->m_lSerialNumber).c_str());
barcode->LinkEndChild(textbarcode); 

instead of the char array. Still the xml appears like below:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestData>
<Operator>Demo test</Operator>
<ParentBarcode>01489
</ParentBarcode>
<Measurements>
The problem as before is that the tag does not close on the same line. Nothing changed.. Anything I am still doing wrong? Can't see it. If not, anyway to move the closing tag on the same line, by adding more code?